# Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded installed virtual box on my ubuntu. Aim was to work on windows. Watched the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_3r5U67Fu4

Everything went cool but on starting the new virtual OS, got this message in the black box.

[image: Opening screen on starting the OS]

please help.

Comment: Does your Win10.vdi have a windows operating system installed on it?

Comment: Seems like a windows related problem to me :) Did you install Windows?

Comment: You need to install Windows in the VM - you need to find a Windows ISO or DVD for this, and then add it to the VM (Devices menu), and install Windows in the VM.

Comment: I guess he's already using installer image when install windows 10 since he's referring to youtube video.